# Symfony write to parameters.yaml from controller

Tags: php, configuration, symfony

I want to write an integer value from a controller to parameters.yaml. Is that even possible?

Example:

**parameters.yaml**

```
parameters:
    # ...
    counter: 13
```

**SomeController.php**

```
class SomeController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $counter = $this->getParameter('counter');
        $counter++;
        // now save new counter value to parameters.yaml !??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters are generally fixed values.
So A better approach is probably writing into an individual yaml file:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Dumper;


const MY_PARAM=13;

//manipulate and do your thing....
$array=['my_param'=>self::MY_PARAM++];



$dumper = new Dumper();

$yaml = $dumper->dump($array);

file_put_contents('/path/to/file.yml', $yaml);
```

Then you read the file wherever you need it in your application.

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

$yaml = new Parser();

$value = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.yml'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters.yml must contain only fixed configuration values ! You should store your counter in database or (i don't like this) in txt file.

But if you really want to edit it. You have to parse the file and search / replace the line ... It's really a bad practice !

Comment: But it's just a single value?! Doesn't make much sense to me to create a database table just for that. I think I will put it into a txt file.